# Correspondence between set of paths

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $x,y \in X$. Denote by $P(x,y)$ the set of equivalence classes of paths in $X$ from $x$ to $y$ under the relation: Homotopic equivalence relative to $\{0,1\}$. Then Can we say that $\exists$ a one-to-one correspondence between $P(x,y)$ and $P(x,x)$ if and only if $P(x,y) \neq \varnothing$?

Comment: I got uncertain... How do you mean 'Homotopic equivalence *relative to $\{0,1\}$*'?

Comment: @Berci, $H(t,0)=x$ and $H(t,1)=y$, for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Great. Anyway, $P(x,x)$ is never empty, so in case $P(x,y)=\emptyset$, it *cannot have* bijection with $P(x,x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, supposed you mean $P(x,y)\ne\emptyset$ instead:

So, whenever $x$ and $y$ are *connected by a path* $p$, we have a bijection between $P(x,x)$ and $P(x,y)$: loop $u$ is mapped to the concatenation $up$ and path $q:x\leadsto y$ is mapped to $qp^{-1}$. For the hotomopic relation, use that $pp^{-1}$ is homotopic to the constant loop.